# Element Modification in Multi-Dimensional Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have created a 2-D array in Java and I wish to change the value of each element.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish

-number each student from 1-10

-give each student 5 random marks from 40-100

```
int[][] students = new int[10][5];
Random numGen = new Random();

for (int i=0; i < students.length; i++){
    students[i] = i;         //Problem here..        
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
        students[i][j] = numGen.nextInt(40)+61
    }
}
```

I am having issues assigning each student a number from 1-10.

Where I wrote '//Problem here', is where the compiler keeps giving me trouble.

What is the appropriate method for modifying a single element in multi-dimension arrays?

Comment: Dont you think that instead of having 5 columns in your two dimensional array, you should have 6, one for student number from 1 to 10 and remaining 5 for marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array indices in java starts from `0`. Which means 1st row is represented as 0. To edit an element in a 2D array you need to specify the both indices.
For example to edit an element at `5th row` and `4th column` you should use `myArray[4][3]`. Because you start counting from 0. `myArray[0][0]` is first element of the first row.

```
int[][] students = new int[10][5];
Random numGen = new Random();

for (int i=0; i < students.length; i++){
    students[i][0] = i; //Change student[i] = i to student[i] = i+i
                        // because i starts  from 0 but student number starts from 1.       
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
        students[i][j] = numGen.nextInt(40)+61
    }
}
```

Comment: The code sets students[i][0] to i, and then resets it to the value of [j] in the following loop.  This is not what was intended

Answer (score 1):

Just use the index into the students (and return id as index+1 when you need to).

```
int[][] students = new int[10][5];
Random numGen = new Random();

for (int i=0; i < students.length; i++){     
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
        students[i][j] = numGen.nextInt(40)+61
    }
}
```